# typed stop on my android and it has stoped or freezed

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I've typed 'stop' in terminal emulator on my lava fuel f1 and it has gotten stopped/Freezed. How to undo or deploy the command. Please help.

Comment: Try to hold the power button until the device reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the phone on and off. Different key combinations on different devices will force a reboot. For example, on my Nexus 5 volume down plus power will force a reboot. Play with the different keys until you get it. On Samsung you need the home button, etc.